# How do I access a variable in a button action in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I cannot access the variable incomeValue in the savingsGoal function. Xcode gives me the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'incomeValue'.

```
@IBAction func incomeSliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var incomeValue = Double(sender.value)
    currentIncomeLabel.text = ("$\(incomeValue) /yr")
}
@IBAction func savingsSliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var savingsValue = Int(sender.value)
    savingsLabel.text = ("\(savingsValue)% of income")

    println("savings value \(savingsValue)%")
}
@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        println("first segement clicked")
    case 1:
        println("second segment clicked")
    default:
        break;
    }
}
@IBAction func calculateButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
}


func savingsGoal () {
    var futureIncome = incomeValue + (incomeValue * 3.8)
}
```

}

Comment: Make it a member variable

Comment: Declaring your variable inside the func limits the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you declared `incomeValue` inside your `incomeSliderChanged(_:)` function. This limits the scope of `incomeValue` to that function, meaning you can only reference it from withing the opening `{` and closing `}` of `incomeSliderChange(_:)`. To fix this declare your `incomeValue` variable outside of the function.

```
var incomeValue: Double = 0.0 // You can replace 0.0 with the default value of your slider

@IBAction func incomeSliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    // Make sure you get rid of the var keyword.
    // The use of var inside this function would create a 
    // second incomeValue variable with its scope limited to this function
    // (if you were to do this you could reference the other incomeValue
    // variable with self.incomeValue).
    incomeValue = Double(sender.value)
    currentIncomeLabel.text = ("$\(incomeValue) /yr")
}

func savingsGoal() {
    // You can now access incomeValue within your savingsGoal() function
    var futureIncome = incomeValue + (incomeValue * 3.8)
}
```

If you are new to programming, I recommend reading about the concept of Scope: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)